# trumbowyg emoji implementation

Tags: jquery, plugins, emoji, trumbowyg

I have some trouble with trumbowyg emoji plugin.

The dropdown emoji is display but not the emoji icon list, (only the text content as :smile: for example).

```
../js/Trumbowyg/dist/trumbowyg.min.js
..js/Trumbowyg/dist/plugins/emoji/trumbowyg.emoji.js

$('#element').trumbowyg({
    autogrow: true,
    btns: [
        ['viewHTML'],
        ['formatting'],
        'btnGrp-semantic',
        ['superscript', 'subscript'],
        ['link'],
        ['emoji'],
        ['insertImage'],
        'btnGrp-justify',
        'btnGrp-lists',
        ['horizontalRule'],
        ['removeformat'],
        ['fullscreen']
    ]
});
```

Any ideas?